# How to reference generated permissions in Django 1.7 migrations

Tags: python, django, permissions, migration

I'm trying to create a auth.Group with permissions automaticly with migrations. My problem is that when I run migrate on empty database the migration that tries to attach permission to the group can't find the permission. If I target an earlier migration so that migrate exits without an error the permissions appear into the database and after that the migration code can find the permission. So what can I do so that the migration can reference a permission which is created in an earlier migration when the migrations are run back to back?

```
def load_data(apps, schema_editor):
    Permission  = apps.get_model('auth', 'Permission')
    Group       = apps.get_model('auth', 'Group')

    can_add = Permission.objects.get(codename='add_game')
    developers = Group.objects.create(name='Developer')

    developers.permissions.add(can_add)
    developers.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myApp', '0004_game'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_data),
    ]
```

The game model is created in an earlier migration. This code causes always an error stating that Permission matching query does not exist when I run it with other migrations on an empty database.
I'm using python 3.4 with django 1.7.2

Comment: is `add_game` permission created in the `0004_game` migration?

Comment: It's one of the default permissions that is created for every model (add, change, delete). It is created into the database in `0004_game` with the model if the migration targets `0004_game` but if all migrations are run in series on an empty database the 0005 migration can't find the permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh. 4 years later...
To create permissions Django uses [post_migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-migrate) signal.

Therefore, when running all migrations at a time, permissions do not yet exist.

Therefore, you can take out your function, for example, in the *management* command.

However, you can still do it like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions


APPS = [
    ...your app labels
]


def create_applications_permissions():
    for app in APPS:
        app_config = django_apps.get_app_config(app)
        create_permissions(app_config)


def load_data(apps, schema_editor):
    create_applications_permissions()
    Permission  = apps.get_model('auth', 'Permission')
    Group       = apps.get_model('auth', 'Group')

    can_add = Permission.objects.get(codename='add_game')
    developers = Group.objects.create(name='Developer')

    developers.permissions.add(can_add)
    developers.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myApp', '0004_game'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_data),
    ]
```

And to create permissions do not use apps passed to the migration. Will not pass the check in `create_permissions`:

```py
if not app_config.models_module:
    return
```

But you have to be careful.

I hope someone will be useful.

Comment: What if I have only one app?

Comment: In Django 3.2.5+ add ("contenttypes", "0002_remove_content_type_name") to your dependencies. A migrations has been added (0002) removing the 'name' field. This migration is fairly low in the migration tree and therefore might not be applied yet when you create the permissions, resulting in django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "name" of relation "django_content_type" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (1, null, admin, logentry)

Comment: As a matter of fact.. just add ("auth", "0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length") (or which ever seems appropriate for your use case). This way you know for sure the Permissions and ContentType exists